# Strange gap between header and body

Tags: header

I've been trying hard, but I can't find the reason. Check www.kanionek.pl
How to get rid off the gap between the header and top of the window? There's .site: 15px auto, but even if I reduce it to 0 there's still 21px extra. Hope you can help.

I know I can use negative margin, but I would like to know the reason. Part of header:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'dream' ); ?></a>

<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="site-branding">
```

Part of template:

```
<?php


get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

css fragments:

```
.site{
max-width: 960px;
margin: 15px auto;
   border: 2px solid #808080;
   border-radius: 10px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Header margin and padding set to 0 do not help.
Body padding and margin are set to 0 and the only trace is that when I change css body section line-height to "0" that gap is gone.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: It's based on wordpress. Here comes header:

Comment: As pointed out, you should add the relevant CSS and HTML. You might also want to consider adding a screenshot showing the problem. Once it is fixed future visitors should be able to understand this question without being able to visit the site.

Comment: Part of header: <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
 <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'dream' ); ?></a>

 <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="site-branding">
        
  <?php
        if( ( of_get_option( 'dream_show_header_logo_text', 'text_only' ) == 'both' || of_get_option( 'dream_show_header_logo_text', 'text_only' ) == 'logo_only' ) && of_get_option( 'dream_header_logo_image', '' ) != '' ) {
        ?>

Comment: When I use Firefox inspector there's <title> displayed in body section, however it's set as display:none so I do not think it might cause the problem.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, add it to the original question instead by editing it.

Comment: And also post the CSS

Comment: Don't know if it is causing your problem, but you should move all the `meta`, `link`, `title`, `script` and `style` tags (basically everything between the start of the `body` and the first `div`) into the `head` where it belongs.

Comment: No, that's not it. There's nothing between body and #page that might be displayed so I find it really confusing. That's my first time on stackoverflow so please do not kick me too hard for not putting everything the way you are used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is adding a [zero width no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) right after the `<body>` tag, forcing the following block-display `<div>` down one line. Probably one of the many scripts. I couldn't tell what, but there you go.

To see it, open the Firefox inspector, right-click on the `<body>` tag, and click "Edit as HTML". Right after the tag there is (at least in my Firefox) a red dot which is the placeholder for that invisible character. You can copy it and paste it into something that will tell you the codepoint etc.

Comment: Thank you - seems like I need to find that /ufeff. I probably used wrong text encoding during editing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem - maybe it will help someone some day. I could not locate exactly zero-width char, but being almost sure it should be in header.php, I opened it notepad++ and saved using utf-8 without BOM encoding.